# Air application - busycursor

Tags: air, httpservice

I have a air application with several windows. When I go for a
httpservice, the busy cursor appear backside of the current window (it appear on the inital window).
Can anybody help me to position the busy cursor in  front of all
windows.

Comment: Hi Isabelle,
How and where have you implemented the httpservice query? MXML? AS? If AS, how do you set the busyCursor? Which CursorManager do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Kodiak,

The [HTTPService documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#showBusyCursor) describes the showBusyCursor parameter, which I assume isabelle is using.  If using MXML, you'd just add a parameter showBusyCursor="true".  If using AS, you'd set the property myHttpServiceObject.showBusyCursor=true

isabelle,

I traced the .showBusyCursor=true AS call.  I put breakpoints on the "function get showBusyCursor()" calls in HTTPService and AbstractOperation.  AbstractOperation.invoke calls CursorManager.setBusyCursor(), which is unfortunate.

There's a note in the [CursorManager documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cursormgr_3.html) that says

> In AIR, each mx.core.Window instance uses its own instance of the CursorManager class. In an AIR application, instead of directly referencing the static methods and properties of the CursorManager class, use the Window.cursorManager property to reference the CursorManager instance for the Window instance.

I read this to mean that there is no truly global place to set the cursor - it's done on a per-window basis.

The only solution that comes to mind is to listen for the invoke and result events from HTTPService and set the cursor manually in each window using this.cursorManager.setBusyCursor() and this.cursorManager.removeBusyCursor().

I hope someone else can add to this - in my application I've a half dozen different window types and a lot of HTTPService calls.  This could result in some terribly messy code.